# how to send data server to another server using curl?

Tags: php, curl

To be clear, I want the page containing my form (page1.php) to check the data entered by the user from my other server page (https://anotherserver.com/checker) and send it to page1.php as true or false. This is my first time using curl. I can't see anything with this code..

here is my form page code `page1.php`

```
function dataFn($url, $data = array()) {
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 3000);
    $data = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return json_decode($data, true);
}

$data = dataFn(base64_encode('my base64 key'), ['value1' => $value2, 'value2' => $value2]);

var_dump($data);
die();

if (!$data) {
    // some err
} else {
    if ($data['status'] == 0) {
        // some code
    }
}
```

here is my checker server page

```
<?php 
// validation page
    print_r($_POST['value1']);
?>
```

Comment: dataFn expects first argument a URL, but is not. `base64_encode('my base64 key')` <-- that's not a URL.

Comment: No need for `http_build_query($data)`, just `use $data`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Can you please tell me how to apply it correctly

Comment: The `if` statement won't execute, since you `die()` before that.

Comment: Please read. `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);`.

Comment: @kawindu It works either way. If the value is an array, `curl_setopt` automatically calls `http_build_query()`. It's not related to whatever problem you're having.

Comment: As @MarkusZeller said, the first argument to `dataFn()` should be the URL of the cherk page, not a key.

Comment: Thanks, both of you. i'll check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't make too many errors.  It definitely will not with your code.

Two ways to make your post data.

```
$post = 'key1=value1&key2=value2&key3=value3';
$post = array('key1'=>value1,'key2'=>value2,'key3'=>'value3');
```

depending on the data you may need to use urlencode()

```
$post = urlencode($post);
```

I do a lot of curl these are my standard post options

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING,"");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING,"");
```

these are my troubleshooting options

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request);
```

You NEED to see the request (out) and response headers (in), so you NEED these these two options.  
These two option must come out after fixing the problem.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
```

If it's HTTPS you need this one:

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

I always make my own request headers.  You can remove that option, it's not mandatory.

```
$request = array();
$request[] = "Host: www.example.com";
$request[] = "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
$request[] = "User-Agent: MOT-V9mm/00.62 UP.Browser/6.2.3.4.c.1.123 (GUI) MMP/2.0";
$request[] = "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5";
$request[] = "Connection: keep-alive";
$request[] = "Cache-Control: no-cache";
$request[] = "Pragma: no-cache";
```

If you are having trouble making the POST you look at the header you send and receive.

```
$data = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)){echo 'Error: ' . curl_error($ch);}
```

Sometimes I will save the all response curl info as text and sometime echo

```
$info = rawurldecode(var_export(curl_getinfo($ch),true));
echo rawurldecode(var_export(curl_getinfo($ch),true));
```

You want the `CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT` from the `curl_getinfo()`
Then you can see what you really sent.

```
echo curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT);
```

The http response id very important to know.

```
$httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
```

There is a lot of info in the curl_getinfo which may give you other hints.

If I had the URL I'm sure I could get it working.